# Zu + adjective + noun, gender endings sometimes ignored?

Tags: gender, declension

I tried to translate these 2 phrases into German:

*too big a desk - zu großer Schreibtisch.*

*too little time - zu wenig Zeit*

So, "Schreibtisch" is masculine so the ending of the adjective before it makes sense.
But why in the second phrase, "wenig" doesn't take the feminine -e ending?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Sie hat zu wenig Zeit.
>
> Er zeigt zu wenig Zuneigung.

This is the adverbial use of the pronoun *wenig*, and that's why it doesn't get adjective endings.

You can break down the grammar of these sentences as *wenig* is not a feature of *die Zeit* or *die Zuneigung* here, but a feature of the verb

> (zu) wenig haben
>
> (zu) wenig zeigen

Think of such common adverb-verb combinations as verbs of their own.

---

The adjective use of *wenig* works like this instead:

> Es lag an **der** (zu) wenigen Zeit, die sie hatte.

The article *der* creates a brace with *Zeit*, which marks all the things inbetween belonging to *der* and *Zeit*. So it has to be an adjective here.

---

To make it even more complicated, even adjectives as *groß* can be used like adverbs:

> Er hatte nicht groß Zeit.

This is *groß* in the meaning of *viel*.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes more sense, but is this just a feature of "wenig, groß"? If I said "zu groß schreibtisch" in which "groß" is a feature of the verb instead of the noun would it also be considered correct?

In the meantime, I can say "zu wenige zeit" and still be correct right as long as I intend "wenig" to be an attributive adjective instead of an adverb?

Comment: *Zu groß Schreibtisch* isn't correct, and *zu viel Schreibtisch* is at least questionable. *Am Ende des Geldes ist bei mir noch zu viel Monat übrig.* is however a common saying. That adverbial use is limited to adverbs that take an attribute, as *kein, wenig, viel, häufig, selten* etc.

Comment: *Zu wenige Zeit* means a slightly different thing than *zu wenig Zeit* but yes, it's correct in the right grammatical context.

Comment: Now it makes sense, thanks for the clarification. I hope this will become even clearer as I am exposed to more content